# Azure DataBricks output is not able to loop in ADF foreach Loop

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks

I am trying to send the array list of Json value to azure data factory ForEach loop from my databricks notebook. there is error and failed my ForEach loop as below message,

[image]

> The execution of template action 'MainForEach1' failed: the result of
> the evaluation of 'foreach' expression
> '@activity('test_notebook').output.runOutput' is of type 'String'. The
> result must be a valid array.

my databricks code as below like,

```
final_df = spark.sql("select * from table1")

def call(row):
    row = row.asDict()
    payload = dict()
    payload["id"] = row.get("t1")
    payload["name"] = "test"
    payload["name2"] = row.get("cname")
    payload["add"] = row.get("add1")
    payload["add2"] = row.get("add2")
    payload["c1"] = row.get("c1")
    payload["s1"] = row.get("s1")
    payload["country"] = row.get("Country")
    payload["code"] = row.get("code")
    response = requests.post(api_endpoint,json=payload,headers=headers)
    return response

list_data=list()
# testing purpose
x = final_df.collect()[1:5]
for row in x:
    api_response =call(row)
    temp = {"details":{},"reason":""}
    temp["edetails"]["input"] = row.asDict()
    temp["edetail"]["output"] = api.text
    if api.status_code != 200:
        temp["s"] = "f"
        temp["reason"] = api.text
    else:
        temp["s"] = "s"
    list_data.append(temp)

dbutils.notebook.exit(list_data)
```

below output for trying builded array from current notebook but adf not accepting this array list.

> [{'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '3231232', 'cname': 'sdasa', 'add1':
> None, 'add2': None, 'c1': None, 's1': None, 'c2': None, 'code': None},
> 'Output': '{"Message":"An error has occurred."}'}, 'Reason':
> '{"Message":"An error has occurred."}', 's': 'f'}, {'EDetails':
> {'Input': {'test': '24431212', 'cname': 'somename', 'add1': 'sfasasd',
> 'add2': 'dsadasdasd', 'c1': 'swqwewqe', 's1': ' ', 'c1': 'asddadasd',
> 'code': 'sads2323'}, 'Output': '{"test":"sad12321312312"}'}, 'Reason':
> '', 's': 's'}, {'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '23232323', 'cname':
> "ffffff", 'add1': '43ddsdsd', 'add2': 'NA', 'c1': 'sdfdsfsdf', 's': '
> ', 'c1': 'Us', 'code': '323dsds'}, 'Output': '{"test":"0232323"}'},
> 'Failure': '', 's1': 's'}, {'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '33sdsd',
> 'cname': "sdasdasdas", 'add1': 'sdadsad', 'add2': 'NA', 'c1': 'sadsd',
> 's1': ' ', 'c1': 'km', 'code': '34eerer'}, 'Output':
> '{"test":"sadsadsads"}'}, 'Failure': '', 's': 's'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got same error when I tried to return your list of dictionaries from Notebook to ADF.

[image]

Due to the `None`  values, it is converting the list of dictionaries to the string when returning the value from Notebook to ADF.

[image]

And that's why you are getting the above error.

To resolve the error, use the below code before returning the value from Notebook.

```
import json

list_data=[{'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '3231232', 'cname': 'sdasa', 'add1': None, 'add2': None, 'c1': None, 's1': None, 'c2': None, 'code': None}, 'Output': '{"Message":"An error has occurred."}'}, 'Reason': '{"Message":"An error has occurred."}', 's': 'f'}, {'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '24431212', 'cname': 'somename', 'add1': 'sfasasd', 'add2': 'dsadasdasd', 'c1': 'swqwewqe', 's1': ' ', 'c1': 'asddadasd', 'code': 'sads2323'}, 'Output': '{"test":"sad12321312312"}'}, 'Reason': '', 's': 's'}, {'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '23232323', 'cname': "ffffff", 'add1': '43ddsdsd', 'add2': 'NA', 'c1': 'sdfdsfsdf', 's': ' ', 'c1': 'Us', 'code': '323dsds'}, 'Output': '{"test":"0232323"}'}, 'Failure': '', 's1': 's'}, {'EDetails': {'Input': {'test': '33sdsd', 'cname': "sdasdasdas", 'add1': 'sdadsad', 'add2': 'NA', 'c1': 'sadsd', 's1': ' ', 'c1': 'km', 'code': '34eerer'}, 'Output': '{"test":"sadsadsads"}'}, 'Failure': '', 's': 's'}]

myjson= json.dumps(list_data)
dbutils.notebook.exit(myjson)
```

It will give the JSON with `null` values instead of `None` values and the Notebook activity `runOutput` also will be a JSON array which you can use in ForEach.

[image]

Comment: I have tried your solution and got fixed issues but if we run full record of the pipeline , I mean we have more 10,000 records loop in databricks and final JSON sent back to ADF pipeline but we are getting error like " length of execution output over limit ( currently 4MB) "

Comment: while using test =  json.dumps(jsonvalue) --> dbutils.notebook.exit(test)

Comment: Yes, there is a limitation on Notebook activity output of 4 MB (approximately 5000 rows) just like limitation on lookup activity output.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73166958/18836744), I know it's a complex method but currently ADF won't support returning more than 5000 rows for any Notebook actvity, web or lookup activity.

Comment: is it required azure storage for you reffered solutions ?

Comment: Yes, databricks writes the files to the storage and ADF access those using Get meta data activity and lookup.